# Script is not running or showing errors

Tags: perl, terminal

I am writing a script that looks at an access_log file to see how many times each search engine was accessed and to see which one is accessed the most. I am sure there are problems with some of my syntax, but I can't even tell since I am not receiving any information back when running it. Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;

$googleCount = 0;
$msnCount = 0;
$yahooCount = 0;
$askCount = 0;
$bingCount = 0;


while (<STDIN>)
{
    if (/(google.com)/)
    {
        $googleCount++;
    }

    if (/(msn.com)/)
    {
        $msnCount++;
    }

    if (/yahoo.com/)
    {
        $yahooCount++;
    }

    if (/ask.com/)
    {
        $askCount++;
    }

    if (/bing.com/)
    {
        $bingCount++;
    }
}



print "Google.com was accessed $googleCount times in this log.\n";
print "MSN.com was accessed $msnCount times in this log.\n";
print "Yahoo.com was accessed $yahooCount times in this log.\n";
print "Ask.com was accessed $askCount times in this log.\n";
print "Bing.com was accessed $bingCount times in this log.\n";
```

I am running MacOS. In the terminal I am typing:

```
perl -w access_scan.pl access_log.1
```

When I press enter, nothing happens.

Comment: Don't write Perl 4 style code. `use v5.10; use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside the fact that your script didn't work as you expected, there are a few things wrong with your script:

In regexes, the dot `.` matches any non-newline character. This includes a literal period, but is not restricted to that. Either escape it (`/google\.com/`) or protect special characters with `\Q...\E`: `/\Qgoogle.com\E/`.

There is a programming proverb “Three or more, use a `for`”. All your conditionals inside your loop *are* the same, except for the regex. You counts are actually one variable. Your report at the end is the same line multiple times.

You can use a hash to ease the pain:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';

my %count;  # a hash is a mapping of strings to scalars (e.g. numbers)
my @sites = qw/google.com msn.com yahoo.com ask.com bing.com/;

# initialize the counts we are interested in:
$count{$_} = 0 foreach @sites;

while (<>) { # accept input from files specified as command line options or STDIN
  foreach my $site (@sites) {
    $count{$site}++ if /\Q$site\E/i; # /i for case insensitive matching
  }
}

foreach my $site (@sites) {
  say "\u$site was accessed $count{$site} times in this log";
}
```

The `\u` uppercases the next character, this is required to produce identical output.
The `say` is exactly like `print`, but appends a newline. It is available in perl5 v10 or later.

Answer (score 3):

The script is trying to read from STDIN, but you are providing the filename to read from as an argument.

"Nothing happens" because the script is waiting for input (which, since you haven't redirected anything to standard input, it expects you to type).

Change `<STDIN>` to `<>` or change the command to `perl -w access_scan.pl < access_log.1`

Comment: Worked perfectly and I didn't even have syntax errors! Such a relief when it is just a silly mistake haha. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @jlot: so you can choose one of the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is reading from stdin, but you're providing your input as a file. You need to [redirect](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) thus:

```
perl -w access_scan.pl < access_log.1
```

The `< file` construct provides the contents of your file as the standard input for your script.

Answer (score 0):

The script works fine (I tested it), but you need to feed it with the log in the STDIN:

```
cat access_log.1 | perl -w access_scan.pl
```

Comment: That is a useless use of `cat`, see the [jargon file](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) for details.